# Declaring an ArrayList object as final for use in a constants file

Tags: java, arraylist, constants, global, final

I am generating an ArrayList of objects. 
Following is the code

```
ArrayList someArrayList = new ArrayList();

Public ArrayList getLotOfData()
{
ArrayList someData = new ArrayList();
return someData; 
}


someArrayList = eDAO.getLotOfData();
```

Once I have this ArrayList object "someArrayList", I would like to declare it public and final and store it in a Constants file so that it can be accessed globally. 
Is there a way I can do that? If I declare an Arraylist object public and final, then I would not be able to reassign any values to it. 
I tried the following

```
public final ArrayList anotherArrayList = new ArrayList();

anotherArrayList.addAll(someArrayList);
```

I had hoped to store this "anotherArrayList" as a global ArrayList object and use it, but this returns a nullpointer exception.   I want to use it just like a String constant  "ConstantsFile.anotherArrayList". Any ideas???

Comment: can someone please edit this?

Comment: You're actually a bit confused; declaring a variable final means only that you can't set the reference to something else, not that you can't add objects to it.

Comment: @Dave...I am also surprised as to why this returns a nullpointer exception

Comment: Let me get this straight: You got a NullPointerException, and rather than looking at the stacktrace or debugging to find out what is null, you turn to stackoverflow to write your code for you. A much better question to ask would be how you can locate the cause of a NullPointerException - provided that questions hadn't been answered over and over, of course.

Comment: @Raghu Why what "returns" an NPE?

Comment: @Raghu Will you accept an answer? If none of the answers are acceptable, please state what else you are seeking from an answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides [`ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) for just about this reason.  (Also, it doesn't have the unnecessary space overhead that `ArrayList` allocates to make room for future elements which you won't be adding for your application.)

```
public static final ImmutableList<String> CONSTANTS = 
  ImmutableList.of("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 100):

You can easily make it `public static final`, but that won't stop people from changing the *contents*.

The best approach is to *safely publish* the "constant" by:

- wrapping it in an unmodifiable list
- using an instance block to populate it

Resulting in one neat final declaration with initialization:

```
public static final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(
    new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("foo");
        add("bar");
        // etc
    }});
```

or, similar but different style for simple elements (that don't need code)

```
public static final List<String> list = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

Answer (score 32):

Java 1.4 compatible way:

```
public static final List STRINGS = Collections.unmodifiableList(
    Arrays.asList(new String[] {"foo", "bar"}));
```

Such List is unmodifiable, calling methods such as `add()`, `remove()` or `set()` will cause `UnsupportedOperationException`.

For less ancient Java versions:

```
public static final List<String> STRINGS = Collections.unmodifiableList(
    Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

And finally, Java 9 comes with:

```
public static final List<String> STRINGS = List.of("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 9 the solution is super simple.

You do not even need Guava, since we have:

```java
    public static final List<String> list = List.of("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can create a final ArrayList and then make it unmodifiable. It involves creating a class to hold the final ArrayList.

First, make your list, doing all the mutations you need to do.

Second, create a class that will create the final ArrayList in its constructor.

```
public class Wrapper {

    final List<T> list;
   
    // Other final variables to be set and added to the constructor.

    public Wrapper(List<T> list) {
        this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

}
```

This is useful for when you need an immutable class with a List.

Comment: This is what `Collections.unmodifiableList()` does - returns a wrapper. Using this class adds no value: ie `new Wrapper(myList)` is effectively the same as `Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.unmodifiableList(myList))`. Why would the caller use you class and not just use `Collections.unmodifiableList(myList)`? Also note that making the field `final` is not required - not providing a setter is enough.

Comment: When you need a immutable class with a List. Said immutable class could have any number of members.

Comment: What if you need two lists? Or 100? The logical approach is to use multiple `Wrapper`, then we're back to just using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. Anyway, this doesn't actually answer the question, which asks how to declare an immutable list of Strings that is a constant.

Comment: What if you wanted non list members in the wrapper?